# Hide parent with v-onclick Vue 2.0. max-width: 767px

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Trying to build a dropdown-menu that will only be shown when screen is smaller than 767px. There are two requirements here to hide the menu and those are:

If someone clicks outside the menu and when a random router link is being clicked.

```js
export default {
    name: 'navbar',
    data() {
      return {
        isShow: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onClick(e) {
        isShow = false
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<button v-on:click ="isShow = !isShow">Click ME</button>

      <div class="router" v-show="isShow">
        <router-link to="/" class="nav-link" v-on:click.prevent="onClick()">Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/phones" class="nav-link">Phones</router-link>
        <router-link to="/moreproducts" class="nav-link">More Products</router-link>
        <router-link to="/blogs" class="nav-link">Support</router-link>
        <router-link to="/news" class="nav-link">News</router-link>
      </div>
      
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To show the menu according to screensize**

You can use jquery to get browser viewport width.

```
 $(window).width();
```

Then write a function which will check screen width and return true/false.

```
showMenu() {
  let screenWidth = $(window).width()
  if (screenWidth < 767) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

**To hide the menu**

1. Use [Vue Clickaway](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway) to check if someone clicks outside the menu.
2. Write before each navigation guard to hide the menu.

   ```
   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     this.hideMenu() // Hides the Menu
     next()
   })
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in pure Vue instead of using jQuery.

Comment: Use var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;